StoredProcedureQuery with Multiple IN parameter not working after hibernate(6) and java (17) upgrade
After upgrading to Java 17 and hibernate 6, the sequence of IN parameter was changed. I was able to fix this by changing the sequence while sending the IN parameter to the procedure.
But I am migrating my project to java 8 to 17, and by this solution, there are lots of changes in my code. Please suggest some  simple fix, I don't want to change in my java input seq as well in proc sequence. Is there any configuration that disallow the sequence and use named parameter property.
ClassEntity saveFactorResponse = (ResponseEntity) entityManager
    .createStoredProcedureQuery("proc_res", "ClassEntity")
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("id", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("name", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("userName", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("productType", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .setParameter("id", name)  // Ensure this matches the procedure's parameter name
    .setParameter("name", id)
    .setParameter("userName", userName)
    .setParameter("productType", productType)
    .getSingleResult();

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_res] 
@name nvarchar(100),
@id nvarchar(100),
@userName nvarchar(100),
@productType nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Your procedure logic goes here
END

Before migration were are using java 8 with springboot 2.x version. It's working fine, now I am using java 17 with springboot 3.x version, now it used java param sequence.. Like @name has stored userName value, @id store productType value, how to fix.

It is strange hibernate ignoring param names and matching with param position.

Seems like this is something that was changed for oracle as well: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/storedprocedurequery-param-name-binding-in-hibernate-6/8979 unfortunately i don't quite have time to see where the issue is exactly, but perhaps they changed so parameter binding is done by ? instead of building the raw sql. You should try to find out the raw code that's being called in old and new version
